# Перетаскивание img

Tags: изображения, html

Я заметил что когда я сам создаю `<img>` то изображение можно перетаскивать мышью а на сайтах например аватар на Хэшкод'е нельзя перетаскивать
Вопрос от чего это зависит (я знаю что с помощью js можно убрать перетаскивание но помоему это не пременялось в перечисленных мною случаях) можно перетаскивать `img` или нет 
В Opera  и Safari некоторые img  не перетаскиваются а в других все `img` перетаскиваются от чего это зависит?

Например [На моей странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1267/rules) моё фото в Opera и Safari нельзя перетаскивать хотя это обычный img может это из за `alt`? Или из-за чего? Ведь когда я сам создаю 
`img` то он перетаскивается! И кстати я прекрасно знаю html css и js и я спрашиваю от чего зависит перетаскиваемость/неперетаскиваемость тега `<img>` только в некоторых браузерах, без участия JS и CSS**

Comment: Можно, но тут уже надо не тупо спрашивать функцию( такой нет ), а думать самому. Я уже реализовывал что-то подобное. Все успешно работает.

Comment: Да я не ф-цию спрашиваю а ПОЧЕМУ иногда img не перетаскивается а иногда перетаскивается!?

Comment: > в Opera и Safari нельзя перетаскивать 

А вот в огнелисе "перетаскивается" вся графика и аватары в том числе. Чо ж делать то? Ой, бяда... ))

Comment: В от я и говорю что только в Opera и Safari!

Comment: Если бы всё было так просто как кажется я бы не спрашивал!

Comment: У меня в opera все перетаскивается. Иногда это даже мешает )

Comment: Похоже все поняли о чём вопрос, но ответить никто не в состоянии :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Firefox и Opera перемещаются все img. Если нет, значит это запрещено через javascript (проверяется отключением в настройках браузера).

Если Вам нужно запретить перемещение картинок - создавайте над каждой картинкой пустой слой (http://jsfiddle.net/7soft/xpNat/3/) или пользуйтесь скриптом shurik'a. Если наоборот, хотите, чтобы картинка перетаскивалась, напишите drag and drop на javascript для браузеров, которые это не поддерживают.

Answer (score 3):

Если изображение выводится через тег img, то его можно "перетаскивать", а если оно положено через background в цсс, то нельзя.

Comment: Я это знаю но ведь например на Хэшкод img нельзя перетаскивать и Js это не контролирует!

Comment: уточните, что значит перетаскивать img, когда и где их можно перетаскивать?

Comment: А почему вы минусуете мой вопрс и плюсуете ответ @makregistr ведь мой вопрос обоснован (проверте сами если не верите) а ответ дан не в тему (сравните с вопросом) я ведь говорю ПРО ТЭГ IMG с SRC а не background-image и только в некоторых браузерах img не перетаскивается и только при определённых условиях КАКИХ ИМЕННО УСЛОВИЯХ это и суть вопроса!

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать как то [так](http://jsfiddle.net/xpNat/2/)

Comment: 1 Это не совсем работает! (изображение перетаскивается в Opera и IE<8)
2 Это не то что мне нужно! Я спрашиваю от чего зависит перетаскивается или нет ТЭГ IMG БЕЗ ПРИМЕНЕНИЯ CSS/JavaScript причём только в некоторых браузерах !

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]